# Force rack-offline (or Rails) to update caching manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, caching, offline-caching, offline-browsing

I use Rails 4 with [rack-offline](https://github.com/wycats/rack-offline) to cache my pages. I also want to cache (dynamically generated) html pages for offline browsing. Problem is, with the way HTML5 works, they stay stale until the application manifest is updated.

The  docs say:

> In production, it generates a SHA hash once based on the contents of
>   all the assets in the manifest. This means that the cache manifest will
>   not be considered stale unless the underlying assets change.

Is there any way I can trigger a new hash generation when one of my html pages change? This would, for example, after a database update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, because AppCache is meant for static resources. Best to use a static HTML page, and use JavaScript to load in dynamic content.

Check out [appcachefacts.info](http://appcachefacts.info/) for more information.